# XML ingestion to BigQuery using Data Fusion

Tags: xml, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, google-cloud-data-fusion

I am trying to import xml file to BigQuery using Data Fusion. I have converted xml into json using wrangler and defined a pipeline to ingest to BigQuery, but there are no records passing to it. I saw in the logs : Importing into table 'double-balm-262919:ctrma.ctrma_new' from 0 paths; path[0] is '(empty)'; awaitCompletion: true, It should take some path to fetch results. Is there any solution?

Comment: Are there records being passed to Bigquery sink? This can be verified using preview capability

Comment: No, records are not being passed to BigQuery sink. I tried loading a CSV , it works but not for a xml file

Comment: Are there any other errors in the logs? What is the structure of the pipeline? In the preview mode, do you see records being read from the source? If possible could you please attach the pipeline json? Please make sure sensitive information is removed